# SAMBA/Windows Login Require to connect printer with explorer

Tags: windows, login, printing, samba

I have cups working fine on a RHEL server. Printers are already added. I have installed and configured SAMBA on the same server. I have access to it with a windows 10 client through the explorer. I can see my printers BUT I can't connect it (right click on a printer and connect) because there is a username and a password required. What is that login ? Samba users ? or a system user ?
Here is my smb.conf :

```
[global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user
        load printers = yes
        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        use client driver = yes

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = no
        printable = yes
        read only = no
        create mask = 0700
        write list = root
        valid users = root

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /etc/samba/drivers
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = no
        read only = no
        write list = root
        valid users = root
```

Comment: change to "guest ok = yes" . look at "man smb.conf"

Comment: I've modified "guest ok = yes", but I still have the windows asking for login a username and password. For my tests I've tried enter both "system user" and "samba user" which is root but still not working. I checked the "man smb.conf" but I can't see something wrong with my parameters.

Comment: try adding the "map to guest = bad user" line. look at in man.

Comment: I added the parameter "map to guest = bad user" in the [Global] section. I don't have the credentials window anymore. Instead I've an error while connecting to the printer.

Comment: remove the "write list = root" and "valid users = root" from both sections.